# Use Java to validate a remote repository

Tags: java, git, version-control

I'm trying to write a code to validate that a provided URL is correctly configured as a remote repo, such as Git or what have you.

I'm starting out using JGit for working with git repos in java, but I can't find a good way to test if a repo exists at the location. I've tried using LsRemote, but that is not a reliable way of testing whether or not the repo actually exists. Is there a better way to do this?

Ideally, I'd also want to retrieve user commit information from the repository as well, but this step is first.

Answer (score 0):

Using JGit, I've found that using the Git.lsRemoteRepository command works fine, as long as you ensure that https is used and not http.

This works for now, but I may have questions about other things later.